# I need to write a code that prints a T out of T's based on the use input height/width

Tags: python

```
def drawT():
    print(width * "T")
    for i in range(height):
        print(width // 3 * "")
        print(width // 3 * "T")
```

This is what I have but I want it to do the loop differently, I cant figure out how to center the vertical part of the T

Comment: Don't divide by 3. Divide by 2 to find its middle and then work out symmetrically from the midpoint. Careful about even vs. odd width. It might be unnatural and look ugly to have the vertical stroke of the T be 1/3 of the overall width.

Comment: it would be nice to provide a desired output for an example width.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
def drawT(width, height):
    print("T" * width) #prints the horizontal line
    for i in range(height-1):
       a = " " * (width // 2)  # create the space in both sides
       print(a + "T" + a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code wich uses python [format](https://pyformat.info/#string_pad_align), which is slightly more elegant and offers alignment:

```
def drawT():
    print(width * "T")
    for i in range(height):
        print('{:^{width}}'.format('TTT', width=width))
```